# I can't post elements in my json URL file in my API

Tags: javascript, html, rest, api

I want to add some object to a json URL using javascript and HTML. I have an external URL, I can read the file but cannot add objects into it! I wrote this code but it does not seem to work! Please help.

HTML code does only include the div I want to show you

```js
//JavaScript: There is the javascript code    
    
var btnAjouter = document.getElementById("btn-ajouter");
var formData = document.getElementById("form").value;

if(btnAjouter){

  btnAjouter.addEventListener("click", function(){       
    var postData = {
      "prenom": document.getElementById("prenom").value,
      "nom": document.getElementById('nom').value,
      "ville": document.getElementById("ville").value    
    } 

    var creerPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
    creerPost.open("POST", "liste_membres.json");
    creerPost.send(JSON.stringify(postData));    

  });
}
```

```html
<div class=" box-header">
    
  <h1>Ajouter un membre</h1>

  <h2>Remplissez le formulaire ci-dessous</h2>
  <form id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Prénom: </label>
      <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" class="form-control" required="('Vous devez entrer un prénom.')">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Nom de famille: </label>
      <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" class="form-control" required="('Vous devez entrer un nom de famille.')">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Ville de naissance: </label>
      <input type="text" id="ville" name="ville" class="form-control" required="('Vous devez entrer une ville de naissance.')">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="btn-ajouter">Ajouter</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I want to add some object to a json URL using javascript and HTML. I have an external URL, I can read the file but cannot add objects into it! I wrote this code but it does not seem to work! Please help.****

Answer (score 1):

try it with FormData class: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData

```
//JavaScript: There is the javascript code    

var btnAjouter = document.getElementById("btn-ajouter");
var formData = document.getElementById("form").value;

if(btnAjouter){

  btnAjouter.addEventListener("click", function(){       
    var postData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));

    var creerPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
    creerPost.open("POST", "liste_membres.json");
    creerPost.send(postData);    

  });
}
```

But I really don't think that you choose the right endpoint. Why would you want to send data to a json file?

Comment: Thank you for your response :). Actually i want to send data to a json file to add a member to the already existed json data file with members. I have to create an API to read, post, put and remove data from an url and this url is in JSON.

Comment: Ok, btw I recommend you to create the XMLHttpRequest just once per runtime. E.g. under var formData... Otherwise everytime the button is clicked a new XMLHttpRequest-Object will be instanced, which will unnecessary block resources